# Bash script, check numeric variable in in range

Tags: bash

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
JOB_NUM=4

function checkJobNumber() {
    if (( $JOB_NUM < 1 || $JOB_NUM > 16 )); then
        echo "pass"
    fi
}

...
checkJobNumber
...
```

When I try to launch the script I get the message:

```
./script.sh line 49: ((: < 1 ||  > 16 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "< 1 ||  > 16 ")
```

(Please notice the spaces in the error message)

I really don't understand what the problem is. If I do the evaluation manually at the command line, it works.

Also, I tried different evaluations like `if [[ "$JOB_NUM" -lt 1 -o "$JOB_NUM" gt 16 ]];`... still no success.

Comment: It looks as if `JOB_NUM` may be unset by the time the function is called; however, bash arithmetic doesn't require the `$` for expansions. If you write it `(( JOB_NUM < 1 || JOB_NUM > 16 ))` it will be syntactically valid even if the variable is unset – in that case it will evaluate to zero.

Comment: if I do as Mat says, I get the string "Job number is : []" in the output, before the error. I still don't understand what I'm doing wrong. By the way, my JOB_NUM=4 assignment was originally a JOB_NUM=$1 assignment (a direct parameter to the script).

Comment: I should also mention that my function(s) are all on top of the script, I don't do anything to the variable before calling the function. I just dont' copy the code because it would be too off-topic.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but one should generally avoid ALL_CAPS variable names as they are "reserved" for use by the shell, etc. Try adding `set -x` to the top of your script and then run it and see where `JOB_NUM` is set/unset?

Comment: @EtanReisner Thank you for the comments on my deleted answer.  You were right and I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: As suggested I made few more attempts in the rest of the code outside the function call, and I found the problem.

My variables declaration was actually indented this way:

```sh
JOB_NUM=            4
THREAD_NUM=         8
.....
VERY_LONG_VAR_NAME= 3
```

and apparently this hoses the evaulation. BAH! It always worked for me before, so why doesn’t it now?

If I delete the white spaces, the evaluation works:

```
JOB_NUM=4
THREAD_NUM=8
....
VERY_LONG_VAR_NAME=3
```

OK I officially hate `bash` . . . sigh :(

Comment: If you're going to ignore the language's syntax, then yes, you're going to hate the results. I guarantee that adding whitespace after the `=` in an assignment has *never* worked, not in `bash`, not in any `sh`-derived shell.

Comment: Not to mention grumble grumble you didn't show us your actual code in the question… whitespace matters.

Comment: `JOB_NUM=     4` isn't even a valid line in a shell script. Running that will get you an error that `4` isn't a command.

Comment: Guys, you are all right, I think I made some confusion. BTW the reason for not showing the code is because it resides on a machine not connected to the internet... so I just wanted to copy by hand the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

this will work fine

```
#!/bin/bash
JOB_NUM=7

function checkJobNumber() {
if  [ $JOB_NUM -lt 0 ] || [ $JOB_NUM -gt 16 ] ; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
}


checkJobNumber
```

And if you want to check variable during tests you can write in your bash :

set -u

this will generate a message like "JOB_NUM: unbound variable" if variable is not well set